# How to use maven in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

After downloading the source code I right clicked it then "Convert to maven project", isn't it supposed to fix all the errors? It still has more than 10,000 errors.

EDIT: I fixed this by unzipping eclipse with something other than winrar. Winrar didn't unzip files with really long names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is **carefully read the following book**

http://www.sonatype.com/Support/Books/Developing-with-Eclipse-Maven

Comment: Also, I think I deleted the .m2 folder, now it gives me this error:Could not calculate build plan: Plugin